# Was the end of episode 'sting' missing or moved for She-Hulk episode five?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, production, she-hulk-attorney-at-law

Up until episode five of *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law*, after the water colour credits there's usually a post credit sting.

I can't tell if the changing room scene was the sting for that episode or if the sting was missing somehow in my region for Disney plus?

Answer (score 7):

You didn't miss it, and apparently no content was removed or cut resulting in its absence, it just didn't have one.

> *Valia then echoed what head writer/EP Jessica Gao previously told us, that **“not every episode” gets a proper mid-credits scene.***
>
> <sup><sub>[She-Hulk Director on Episode 5's 'Missing' Bonus Scene, What Was Left on Cutting Room Floor](https://www.google.com/amp/s/tvline.com/2022/09/19/she-hulk-episode-5-missing-midcredits-scene-x-man-fantastic-four-sneakers/amp/)</sub></sup>

and

> *Head writer Jessica Gao tells EW that fans can expect to get a post-credits scene in **almost every episode. "I think there's only one or two episodes that don't but nearly every episode has an end-credits scene,"** she says. "It's just a result of the fact that we're all comedy writers. If you give us a chance to do an extra joke, we're going to make an extra joke."*
>
> <sub><sup>[All the She-Hulk: Attorney at Law post-credits scenes (so far) explained](https://ew.com/tv/she-hulk-attorney-at-law-post-credits-scenes-explained/)</sup></sub>